# protection of apk against transfer to another phone

Tags: android, google-play, apk

How to make protection for paid applications Google Play against transfer to another android phone? I tried to embed RSA code that Google Play gives, in my application as follows: 
 `public class MainActivity extends Activity 
private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG ... "; 
...
}`
as it is [written here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html), but it is still possible to transfer application.
In other words prohibit copying apk.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the `apk` from being copied from one device to another.

You might want to implement [app licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html).

Comment: I tried to transfer other paid applications, and they did not open on other devices, but mine is still open.

Comment: That's well possible. Those apps are most likely using some license control method.

Comment: In this case, app licensing is not suitable.